# How to: Explicit Anonymous declaration

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

How can i define and explicit tell to compiler that i want a listof a AnonymousType, from a query?

I dont want to use the "var" keyword

Follows the example:

```
List<string> query =    // Explicit getting a List<string>
(from l in listTest
select l).ToList();
```

Thats what i am trying to do:

```
var query2 = // I would like to use List<´a> instead of var
(from l in listTest
select new
{
_string = l,
Lenght = l.Length
}).ToList();
```

Comment: This is not possible because you are using an anonymous type. If you want to define the type explicit, you.. well.. you need a type.

Comment: That's the exact opposite of an _anonymous_ type.

Comment: Anonymous means you don't know the name of the type. How do you expect to introduce the type to the compiler when you are not supposed to know the name of it?

Comment: I wonder why you want this?

Comment: That's why `var` was presented.

Comment: Not as if it actually had some use, just wondering if theres an explicit declaration. Honestly i try to avoid "var" always i can.By the way I know anonymous types SHOULD use var, just wondering

Comment: Why do you try to avoid var?

Comment: Avoid this: `var foo = MyFunction();`  Do not avoid: `var foo = new TimeSpan();`

Answer (score 3):

The only possible way to define the type of that local variable as the actual type of such a list is to use `var`.  You could type the variable as a less-derived type, for example using `IList` (the non-generic version) or `object` or `dynamic`, but given that the anonymous type does not have a name, there is no way to explicitly name that type.  If you have a need to do so you would need to use a named type instead of an unnamed type.

Of course, if you don't technically want to use a local variable you can use an generic method that takes an action to allow you to use generic method inference rather than local variable type inference to type your identifier.  Using a `Use` method:

```
public static void Use<T>(T item, Action<T> action)
{
    action(item);
}
```

---

```
Use(from l in listTest
    select new
    {
        _string = l,
        Lenght = l.Length
    },
    query => Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", query)));
```

You now have an identifier (technically it's a parameter to a method, not a local) typed as the exact type of that list, without using `var`.

Comment: Warning: Although using `IList` would work, it defeats the whole point of having an anonymous type, since there is no way to access `_string` or `Lenght` now.